# Why are emails from Sent Items being saved in RecoverableItemsPurges folder when sending emails using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

We're using the following [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in Microsoft Graph APIs to send emails from users' mailboxes.

```
 POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail
```

The POST request has a parameter called **saveToSentItems** that controls whether sent emails are saved in the Sent Items folder or not. We have noticed that when **saveToSentItems** parameter is False then the email is not saved to Sent Items but is saved in **RecoverableItemsPurges** folder. This unexpected behavior is not documented anywhere in the docs and we cannot figure out the logic behind it or is it simply a bug in Graph APIs?

Ideally, we don't want the email to be saved anywhere in the mailbox when **saveToSentItems** flag is turned off. Let us know how to achieve this.